# Getting Keyerror when accessing an element in JSON, python

Tags: python, json

I've seen this asked a multitude of times, but I think the JSON I'm looking to access is a bit different. I'm looking at a JSON with this format:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1589135576,
  "level": 20,
  "gender": "Male",
  "status": {},
  "personalstats": {},
  "attacks": {
    "103307874": {
      "code": "cc7bc5ab6fbd54f49a2e879c49e70183",
      "result": "Mugged",
      "chain": 2,
      "modifiers": {
        "fairFight": 3,
        "war": 1,
        }
      },
    "103320473": {
      "code": "3184c1e2c9662fd70a21f03a637cb02e",
      "result": "Mugged",
      "chain": 1,
    "modifiers": {
      "fairFight": 1.07,
      "war": 1,
      }
    },
  }
}
```

There are 98 more "attack" below the first two here.

Now I thought I could access the first attacks result with this code, but it results in a key error. Anyone understand why?

```
currentresponse = requests.get("URL")
json_obj = json.loads(currentresponse.text)
lastresult = json_obj["attacks"][0]["result"]
```

As a "bonus" I can access the result of the attack through the following code.

```
json_obj["attacks"]["103320473"]["result"]
```

Comment: Because `attacks` is not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can't access with `json_obj["attacks"][0]`, because it's not a list, and hence doesn't have indexing like a list. These are nested dicts, so you have to access them by dict rules (access by `key`)

Comment: Thanks! As I understand it dicts are inherently unordered, which is somewhat confirmed by the timestamps for the attacks not being in order. Is there any way I can sort and access the attack with the highest "timestamp" (its in the json but I cut it out of OP for readability) directly? I've worked my way around it by storing all attacks in my db and finding the newest one there, but its not very scalable or clean I think